# Удаление Git shell

Tags: git, github

Когда-то, уже не помню когда, поставил себе на комп (win8 64) GitHub-клиент. Помимо самого *github*, поставился *git shell*.

И что-то тогда видать поставилось криво. Сейчас решил почистить от всякого-старого комп и поставить возможно что-то заново.

Удаляю *github*, а *gitshell* остается, причем ярлык с рабочего стола вроде как рабочий и ссылается куда-то в дебри

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Github...
```

При запуске предлагает поставить тот самый *github*.

Стоит ли просто удалять оттуда руками все, или есть какой-то альтернативный способ? Да, потом скорее всего поставлю *git* или *github*, но хотелось бы чтобы он уж нормально поставился.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Когда будете ставить заново — попробуйте Chocolatey.

Comment: Git или GitHub вряд ли получится. Насколько я понимаю, для GH в любом случае понадобится Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AppData\Local\Github` - директория Гитхаба. При переустановке он там файлы должен заменить. Можно удалить руками всю папку, планета не взорвётся. :)

Comment: а то просто с подозрением отношусь ко всяким скрытым папкам) ну раз планете ничего не угрожает, то ок)